# How to display number of search results in WordPress (Genesis)

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I'm trying to display the number of posts found by a search.

I found this code `$wp_query->found_posts` but can't seem to make it work, any suggestions?

```
<?php

add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_search_title' );

function genesis_do_search_title() {

    $title = sprintf( '<div class="archive-description"><h1 class="archive-title">%s %s %s</h1></div>',  $wp_query->found_posts, apply_filters( 'genesis_search_title_text', __( 'results for:', 'genesis' ) ), get_search_query() );

    echo apply_filters( 'genesis_search_title_output', $title ) . "\n";

}

genesis();
```

Documentation:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page#Display_Total_Results

http://my.studiopress.com/documentation/snippets/

Comment: What is in the `found_posts`? If this is a built-in function there should be documentation on it somewhere

Comment: Okay, that looks good. Have you checked to make sure that `$wp_query->found_posts` has a value?

Comment: Got it working after reviewing the documentation, needed: global $wp_query;

Comment: That's great. Please post how you got it to work in an answer below so that others can learn from what you were able to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`global $wp_query;` needs to be present. The syntaxe used shoud be:

```
global $wp_query;
$total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really find the documentation for genesis hooks so this might not work, but it might be that your action 'genesis_before_loop' is executed before the loop variables are set. Try using 'loop_start' instead.

```
<?php

add_action( 'loop_start', 'genesis_do_search_title' );

function genesis_do_search_title() {

    $title = sprintf( '<div class="archive-description"><h1 class="archive-title">%s %s %s</h1></div>',  $wp_query->found_posts, apply_filters( 'genesis_search_title_text', __( 'results for:', 'genesis' ) ), get_search_query() );

    echo apply_filters( 'genesis_search_title_output', $title ) . "\n";

}

genesis();
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to leave a reply.
Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the solution.
Still displays as " results for: games" instead of "8 results for: games".
The problem seems to be way it is printed, but tried echo and variables with the same results.

Comment: Do you maybe know where I can find the documentation for the genesis framework?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry didn't understand code but if you want to count search result through wp_query, so you can use a counter within the loop and display it outside the loop.

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after further reviewing the documentation and adding:

```
global $wp_query;
```

So the code is:

```
<?php

add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_search_title' );

function genesis_do_search_title() {

    global $wp_query;

    $title = sprintf( '<div class="archive-description"><h1 class="archive-title">%s %s %s</h1></div>',  $wp_query->found_posts, apply_filters( 'genesis_search_title_text', __( 'results for:', 'genesis' ) ), get_search_query() );

    echo apply_filters( 'genesis_search_title_output', $title ) . "\n";

}

genesis();
```

Thank you everyone!